# Selecting correct ArcGisFeatureLayer to query onSingleTap event?

Tags: layers, android, feature-layer, arcgis-android

My problem: I'm working on a Android (ArcGis) Attribute Editor following the [sample code](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/sample-code/attribute-editor/) from their tutorials. The problem occurs when I have more than 1 ArcGisDynamicLayer and, more important, more than 1 ArcGisFeatureLayer.

My question: What is the (correct) approach to IDENTIFY the right Feature Layer to query when I tap on a "field" displayed on the map?

I read a similar question ([Arcgis SDK for Android - Query multiple feature layers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73395/arcgis-sdk-for-android-query-multiple-feature-layers)), but I didn't understand how to use IdentifyTask using only a single tap.

Answer (score 1):

You specify the layers you want to identify in the `IdentifyParameters` [constructor](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/tasks/identify/IdentifyParameters.html).  You can use the `IdentifyTask` on single tap by implementing the `MapView.setOnSingleTapListener()`.